# React-bootstrap not installing due to husky error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, react-bootstrap, husky

I am trying to install react-bootstrap.

Yesterday I managed to successfully install react-bootstrap but I then later uninstalled it. Today I tried to reinstall it in the same project but it gives me the bellow errors.

I then created a new react app as a test in order to try and install react-bootstrap, but it failed with the same errors.

It seems that there is an issue relating to husky, so I installed this package but that did not help either.

I am using macOS.

```
noahgwynn@Noah frontend % npm i react-bootstrap
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/noahgwynn/Documents/code/udemy-mern/frontend/node_modules/@popperjs/core
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c husky install .config/husky
npm ERR! sh: husky: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/noahgwynn/.npm/_logs/2021-02-20T19_52_28_911Z-debug.log
noahgwynn@Noah frontend %  npm install --save react-bootstrap
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/noahgwynn/Documents/code/udemy-mern/frontend/node_modules/@popperjs/core
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c husky install .config/husky
npm ERR! sh: husky: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/noahgwynn/.npm/_logs/2021-02-20T19_55_15_427Z-debug.log
noahgwynn@Noah frontend %
```

Your help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Problem fixed!

Just tried "npm i react-bootstrap" again and this time it worked. It's a couple of hours later, not sure what changed but I'm happy it did.

Comment: try `npm install husky`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I said in the question I tried that. It's all fixed though, see my edit.